# Word VB, Clear all checked fields

Tags: vba, ms-word

i have a word with 15+ VB forms and 20-50 CheckBoxes in each.
How do i clear (if they are cheched) all the CheckBoxes in active form w/o having to write the name of each CheckBox?

Thank you

Comment: Loop controls object (in VBE press F2 and look for `Control`)

Comment: This helps but i am still unable to write it :(

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the job. It must be placed in the UserForm's code sheet.

```
Private Sub ClearCheckBoxes()

    Dim Ctl As MSForms.Control

    For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(Ctl) = "CheckBox" Then Ctl.Value = False
    Next Ctl
End Sub
```